# Special chars in angular variable located in HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, encoding

At a point in my html I'm doing things like this :

```
<li ng-repeat="favorite in favorites track by $index">
  <a ng-href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="changeSVG(favorite)">
    <i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i>{{favorite}}
  </a>
</li>
```

The problem is that sometimes the `favorite` in `ng-click="changeSVG(favorite)"` contains special characters like `'`. So I'm getting errors like this in console :

> Error: [$parse:lexerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unterminated%20quote&p1=s%2042-44%20%5B')%5D&p2=changeSVG('Process%20passageNaN'ordre%20MOB')
>       at Error (native)

How can I prevent this ?

I heard about $sce when looking into it but not sure if it fits my needs and how to use it in my controller.

Here is the `changeSVG()` function :

```
$scope.changeSVG = function (svgName) {
    var defaultZoom = getZoomFromCarto(svgName);

    $scope.currentCartography = svgName;
    $scope.currentZoom = defaultZoom;
    if ($scope.cartoHistory.indexOf(svgName) != -1)
        $scope.cartoHistory.splice($scope.cartoHistory.indexOf(svgName), 1);
    $scope.cartoHistory.unshift(svgName)
    if ($scope.cartoHistory.length > 20)
        $scope.cartoHistory = $scope.cartoHistory.slice(0, 20);

    localStorage.setItem("cartoHistory", JSON.stringify($scope.cartoHistory));
    removeEmbed();
    var svgPath = "SVG/" + $scope.currentLanguage + "/" + svgName + ".svg";
    lastEmbed = createNewEmbed(svgPath, defaultZoom);
}
```

I tried to display the svgPath in the log, it works fine with normal files, but when I try with my file with  (space) and `'` in its name, nothing is displayed.

Comment: have you tried `changeSVG(favorite.toString())` or a regex like `favorite.replace(/\'/g,"\'")` ?

Comment: Good idea, I just tried it, but it didnt work

Comment: and that : `favorite.replace(/\'/g,"&#39;")` or `$sce.trustAsHtml(favorite)`

Comment: I'm not sure the string functions are interpreted when placed like this in the html ng-click. For example I tried to use a non-existant function : `ng-click="changeSVG(blabla(favorite.bleble()))"` and no error occured.
About the $sce, I'm not sure how to use it, what are the requirements in my app and controller ?

Comment: I have an idea..... just do `changeSVG({{favorite}})` and let me know

Comment: No, still the same errors. the $sce might be the proper way, but not sure how to use it.

Comment: just include $sce in your controller dependancy like you do for $scope.

Comment: Nah, still the same. But I'm not sure that `ng-click="changeSVG($sce.trustAsHtml(favorite))"` is the proper syntax to use.

Comment: i can´t reproduce, i create http://codepen.io/luarmr/pen/pJPjXe can you have a look if this make sense? and create another one with the problem?

Comment: You should upload the entire code that allows us to reproduce your problem.  Otherwise, you'll receive guesses and not a real answer. use codepen or jsfiddle

Comment: I can't reproduce it either - http://plnkr.co/edit/r84nBiHzxz0JsC1p73eG?p=preview

Comment: So it might actually come from my changeSVG function ? But I'm not even calling it yet when the error messages is displayed in my console. Still, I added the function into the initial post.

Comment: You would receive such an error if you wrote something like '<a ng-click="changeSVG('a)">.
Don't know why the lexer should later be invoked...
The NaN in your string 'Process passageNaN'ordre MOB' also looks mysterious. Is that a string you would expect in your data?
Can't you log and post what the value of favorites is? Maybe it is not an array at all?

Comment: > You would receive such an error if you wrote something like '<a ng-click="changeSVG('a)">

I think that was it, some php was used and added quotes around the variable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs as Angular replaces that `favorite` at your function call by a string. A solution could be use `$index` as the function parameter, so you can read from the array `favorites` at your controller code adding any validation you may need. And no angular string replacement magic shall occur.

something like:

Template:

```
<li ng-repeat="favorite in favorites track by $index">
  <a ng-href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="changeSVG($index)">
    <i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i>{{favorite}}
  </a>
</li>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.changeSVG = function (index) {
    // Add any validation logic here.
    var svgName = favorites[index];

    var defaultZoom = getZoomFromCarto(svgName);

    $scope.currentCartography = svgName;
    $scope.currentZoom = defaultZoom;
    if ($scope.cartoHistory.indexOf(svgName) != -1)
        $scope.cartoHistory.splice($scope.cartoHistory.indexOf(svgName), 1);
    $scope.cartoHistory.unshift(svgName)
    if ($scope.cartoHistory.length > 20)
        $scope.cartoHistory = $scope.cartoHistory.slice(0, 20);

    localStorage.setItem("cartoHistory", JSON.stringify($scope.cartoHistory));
    removeEmbed();
    var svgPath = "SVG/" + $scope.currentLanguage + "/" + svgName + ".svg";
    lastEmbed = createNewEmbed(svgPath, defaultZoom);
}
```